# Short Stay Schengen Visa for non Eu spouse

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, eu, eu-citizens

i am a German national and living in Germany, and married with a pakistani national. My wife live in Pakistan and has not any EU residence card. we are planning together holidays to Denmark. will we get Schengen visa under DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC? or we need to show all documents like normal tourists.

kind regards
Usman Ali

Comment: Your wife's visa should be issued under the directive.  I don't have time at the moment to write a more substantial answer, but I'll do so in the next day or two if there isn't a satisfactory answer by then.

Comment: Yes thank you, i will wait for your answer.....thank for a positive answer